# Where is IBM Lotus Symphony today?

Tags: software-sources, 8.04, ibm-lotus-symphony

This question sparks from a bug report on LibreOffice forum. Yes, I know much of the functionality of Lotus Symphony was supposedly incorporated into OO about the time LO split off. This question isn't about that. I'm looking for someone who has a copy of the actual .deb squirreled away. It's no longer on my NAS. Yes, I have set up 8.04 32-bit LTS, 12, and a few other "vintage" 32-bit (IBM only release 32-bit Debian). I did so because of this.

https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-804-lts-whole-load-of-apps-going-on

> We will also be making IBM Lotus Symphony available too, packaged up
> for an easy install through the Ubuntu Add / Remove software tool.
> Symphony is IBM’s driver for acceptance of a free and open alternative
> to the ubiquitous Microsoft Office.

Yes, I have edited sources.list and pointed back to
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/
for all of the main entries. What doesn't seem to exist is an "old-releases" directory for any of the "partner" software.

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

So, this question is in two parts.

1. Is there an "archive.canonical.com" for 8.04 or 10.4 today and is that where IBM Lotus Symphony was parked for the installer?
2. does anyone have a .deb from one of the versions laying around?

Thank you.

Comment: [omgubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ibm-office-suite-lotus-symphony-3-released) seems to have a link to a 64-bit .deb made by some user, not sure if it still works

Comment: No. None of the links still work. Even the legit torrent links don't work. Given IBM rolled the codebase into OO and it came from OO, I ass-u-me-d it wouldn't be in "partners"

Comment: The final release of this software was in 2012. I'm not sure how asking for a deprecated piece of software is going to be of interest to anyone using Ubuntu these days. 

Comment: Perhaps not to you or many or even most. When one is trying to evaluate all of the features IBM Lotus Symphony had that never made it into either OpenOffice or LibreOffice after the code was released to them it's of peak interest. The final release of Symphony stand alone was 2012 as you say, but it lived on for many years as the editor in Lotus Notes. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/notes/8.5.3?topic=help-welcome-lotus-notes  Actually lives on today in the HCL product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. AFAIK there is no public archive of the partner repository from Canonical.
2. The Internet Archive seems to have some files in http://web.archive.org/web/20110721220655/http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/symphony/.

Comment: You da whatever binary or non-binary designation you prefer! Exactly what I was looking for! Did not think IA stored Binary files let alone Debian packages.

Answer (score 0):

The 64-bit 3.0 version is in archive https://web.archive.org/web/20120310100733/http://www.photofiltre-lx.org/symphony_3.0-1_maverick_amd64.deb.

I'm only answering late is because I have been searching for this version and this question/answer kept coming up in my searches.